# Extract superagent request into a method/function?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, superagent

I'm new to this so please be gentle :-)

I have a couple of unit tests that all share the same superagent request for Get and Post.

Is it possible to extract these requests so that I can just run a function instead of copy pasting the entire request?

Example:

```
var url = URL_GOES_HERE;

it('responds with totalPrice = 0 when numOfDays = 0', function(done) {
request(url)
    .post('/bookRoom')
    .send({"numOfDays": 0, "checkInDate": todayDate})
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .end(function(err, res){
        var body = res.body;
        expect(body.totalPrice).to.eql(0);
        done();
    });
```

I'd like to extract this to a function that would take parameters (such as the JSON being posted) and that i'd be able to do assertions on it, as seen in the example - expect(body.totalPrice).to.eql(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Set it up as a callback:

```
var url = URL_GOES_HERE;

function postBookRoom(postBody, cb) {
    request(url)
        .post('/bookRoom')
        .send(postBody)
        .set(...etc etc...)
        .end(cb); // The callback will be called with parameters err and res
}

it('responds with totalPrice = 0 when numOfDays = 0', function (done) {
    postBookRoom({
        'numOfDays': 0,
        'checkInDate': todayDate
    }, function (err, res) {
        // This is the function that postBookRoom will call back
        expect(res.body.totalPrice).to.eql(0);
        done();
    });
});
```